# Android - strange dot showed up

Tags: android

I restarted my phone when suddenly this showed up:

[image: Picture of my phone]

When I take a screenshot it is not included, this picture was taken using the webcam of my laptop. Anyone knows what it is and how I can remove it?

Comment: what is your phone?

Comment: Huawei P20 Lite

Comment: Seems your screen is broken?

Comment: I can drag it around

Comment: turn off the navigation dock @One_Up

Comment: How do I turn off the navigation dock?